# How to pass an array from Symfony 2 controller to a TWIG template ?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I can`t pass an array from a symfony 2 controller to a TWIG template. I use this code in the controller:

```
$searchTerms['color'] = "Red";
return $this->render('TestBundle::search.html.twig', 
        array(
            "searchTerms" => $searchTerms));
```

In the twig template, I am trying to access the variable like this:

1. {{ searchTerms['color'] }}
2. {{ searchTerms.color }}

Both output nothing, empty string, so it seems like array comes to template but its elements are empty.

What`s wrong?

Comment: Both syntaxes work for me (I just copied and pasted your code into a project of mine). Can you post the whole code of your controller and template?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this code works. The first thing to check is that your twig code is in the correct page (`TestBundle::search.html.twig`). This might sound silly but that happens sometimes...

If this is all good, I suggest that you try to debug within your template. *Debugging is the most important thing*. You will always have this kind of problem while programming, especially when you try something new. The better you are at debugging your code, the better you are as a programmer because there is no way you can get everything right the first time.

### So, how can you debug?

To debug within your twig template, you can use the [debug extension of twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/debug.html). To activate the debug option, you will have to do a quick [change](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#debugging) in your config file. You can also read this [thread](http://hectorpinol.com/twig-debug-in-symfony-2/) if your lost.

You can debug any variable within your template like this:

```
<pre>
{% debug searchTerms %}
</pre>
```

This way, you can easily debug your variable and test what your problem is:

```
{% debug searchTerms['color'] %}
```

If you want to debug things quickly, I highly recommend that you use the [LadyBugBundle](https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle). It is an awesome tool that will allow you to do something like that:

**In your controller:**

```
ladybug_dump($searchTerms);
```

**In your TWIG template:**

```
{{ searchTerms|ladybug_dump }}
```

Not that different from a classic `var_dump` option, but if you have long arrays or objects, `ladybug` will impress you. More importantly, in a controller,  you will often have the need to stop the code at a certain point to avoid the page to load after your debug statement, this is fairly easy with ladybug:

```
ladybug_dump_die($searchTerms);
```

You can even ask **ladybug** to load the "debugged" variable into Symfony profiler with this simple statement.

```
$this->get('ladybug')->log($searchTerms);
```

You have now direct access of the variable from a tab of the Symfony2 profiler.
**Ladybug** can do a lot more, but for this, the [doc](https://github.com/raulfraile/LadybugBundle/blob/master/README.md) is really good.

Comment: I found a problem, there is nothing connected with symfony 2 and twig: I just misprint $searchTerms as $seacrhTerms in one place of controller, but thanks for debug tools it helps me.

Answer (score 3):

I think you must change template like this:

```
{% for item in searchTerms %}
    {{ item.color }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

See official documentation: [Creating and using Templates->embedding-controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers)